# React: can't update the state of Status, no re-render

Tags: reactjs

I have been working with react for a few weeks and have encountered a problem when trying to create a todo app. When I want to update the state of status in handleStatus(), nothing happens in the browser.

```
handleStatus(event) {
      let newStatus;
      const changeState = event.status == 'done' ? newStatus = 'open' : newStatus = 'done';
      
      this.setState({ status: newStatus });
```

Why I can't update this state like I did with the others? Does anyone have a solution?
Thank you very much.

Here is the full code:

```
import React from "react";
import { InputBar } from "./InputBar";
import { Todo } from "./Todo";

const emptyForm = {
  enterTodo: ""
  
};



export class TodoTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        enterTodo: "",
        todos: this.props.todos,
        status: 'open'
      };
      this.handleEnterTodo = this.handleEnterTodo.bind(this);
      this.handleStatus = this.handleStatus.bind(this);
      this.handleCreateTodo = this.handleCreateTodo.bind(this);
      this.handleClearTodos = this.handleClearTodos.bind(this);
      this.handleDeleteTodo = this.handleDeleteTodo.bind(this);
 
    }
    //Textbox Input handler
    handleEnterTodo(event) {
      
      this.setState({
        enterTodo: event.target.value
      });
    }
    //Status handler
    handleStatus(event) {
      let newStatus;
      const changeState = event.status == 'done' ? newStatus = 'open' : newStatus = 'done';
      
      this.setState({ status: newStatus });

    }

    //delete todo
    handleDeleteTodo(event) {
      let todo = this.state.todos;
      todo.splice(this.state.todos.indexOf(event), 1)
    
      this.setState({ todo });
     
    }
   
    //Create Todo
    handleCreateTodo(event) {
      const todo = {
        id: this.state.todos.length,
        describtion: this.state.enterTodo,
        status: 'open'
      };

        this.setState({
          todos: [todo, ...this.state.todos]
        })
        this.state.enterTodo = emptyForm.enterTodo; // Überarbeiten
      
    }

    //Clear Todo List 
    handleClearTodos(event) {
      let CleanedTodos = []
      
      this.state.todos.forEach((element, index) => {

        if(this.state.todos[index].status == 'open'){
            CleanedTodos.push(this.state.todos[index]);
        } 
        
      });

      this.setState({ 
        todos: CleanedTodos
       });
    }

    render() {

      return (

        <>
          <InputBar

            handleCreateTodo={ this.handleCreateTodo }
            handleEnterTodo={ this.handleEnterTodo }
            enterTodo={ this.state.enterTodo }
            handleClearTodos={ this.handleClearTodos }
          />
          <Todo

            handleStatus={ this.handleStatus }
           
            todos={ this.state.todos }
            handleClearTodos={ this.state.handleClearTodos }
            handleDeleteTodo= { this.handleDeleteTodo }
          />
        </>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: hey what is your todo component looking like ? I think your probably not using event.target.value instead of event.status ? it all depends on how your passing the event of clicking or updating the status to done if its something like 

onclick={handleStatus} 

if its a p then something like 

<p value="heyy" onClick={(e) => console.log(e.target.getAttribute("value"))}>Something</p>

Comment: Not sure that's the problem but your using the terniary operator in the wrong way, the correct syntax is: `const newStatus = event.status === 'done' ? 'open' : 'done';`

Comment: There are two arrays in todos. The first is for the todos with the status open and the second for those with the status done. A function runs through todos and checks the status with a for loop and an if query to then store the todos in one of the two arrays. In the render function, both arrays are rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Remember if your are keeping the status of done in this component then all the todos in the todo table will show they are of the status done
```

the best way would be each todo having its own local state of done so that each done state is unique and then handle it something like this

```
<p value="heyy" onClick={(e) => console.log(e.target.getAttribute("value"))}>Something</p>
```

OR

```
const Todo = (props) => {
const [done, setDone] = useState(false)
return <p onclick={() => setDone(true)} >{todo}</p>
}

    todos.map(todo => {
    return <Todo />
    })
```